# where to host my silverlight web application

Tags: silverlight, hosting, silverlight-4.0

I would like to host my silverlight webapplication. What is the best web hosting company for this application?
Regards,

Comment: This should probably be on superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

I have had pretty good experience with webhost4life.com if cheap and non-mission critical is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Any hosting company can provide this service - Silverlight imposes no requirements on the server other than setting up the XAP mimetype.  I would just go with a company I already know and trust :-).